# Makefile for a basic kernel module

Tags: linux, makefile

The following Makefile aims to create a basic Module in the kernel 2.6. And so, I really would like if somebody explain to me the command lines in this Makefile:

```
obj−m += hello−1.o
all:
       make −C /lib/modules/$(shell uname −r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
       make −C /lib/modules/$(shell uname −r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

One further question : Being in a 2.6 kernel, should I replace `hello-1.o` by `hello-1.ko`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line tells the kernel makefile that `hello-1.o` should be used to build a module. The kernel makefile will handle the extension itself; you should not change it.

The third and fifth lines invoke the kernel makefile to build/clean a module, passing it the directory it should look for source files in.

The rest is all standard makefile boilerplate.

See [`Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt) in the kernel documentation for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I thumb up. The link to the document is so helpful.